# Setting fetch size to negative number

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, c3p0

I'm working with someone else's code, which contains the lines:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(myQuery);
```

I was wondering if someone could explain the effect of setting the fetch size to Integer.MIN_VALUE? That is, does it fetch the maximum number of rows possible to memory, or does it behave otherwise?

I should mention that our data source is a C3P0 connection pool, which  uses the MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: [It would throw an SQLException?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int))

Comment: I would think so too, but the code has been working for over a year now. It's possible that the fetch size is incorrect, but the hint is being ignored.

Comment: @KevinL Welcome to the world of non-standardness that is MySQL...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) (which explicitly show the two `createStatement`/`setFetchSize` lines in an example code snippet):

> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row.

In the spirit of teaching to fish, my google search was "mysql fetch size jdbc".

Comment: In the spirit of hiring the painter to paint your new home while you take a trip to the Hamptons, thank you :)