# Does MySQL use server-side pre-fetching when streaming a ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cursor, resultset

The MySQL JDBC connector defines two fetch modes:

- the default one fetches the whole ResultSet at once
- streaming, when the [statement fetchSize is set to Integer.MIN_VALUE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html)

According to the documentation, the streaming will fetch each row individually, one at a time.

1. Is it true that, when using streaming, each row is fetched in a separate database roundtrip?
2. Does the MySQL server prefetches the result-set in advance or does it traverse the server-side cursor one row at a time too?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346229/does-mysql-connector-j-buffer-rows-when-streaming-a-resultset ?

Comment: It could be, although that question actually contains two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the short answer is yes.  I don't know the nuances as it applies to a `mysql_use_result`/`mysql_store_result`, but there are a few types of prefetch:

- The InnoDB storage engine underneath has read-ahead, so it will start fetching pages in advance.
- Some queries do need to be materialized in full before they can be streamed row at a time (think of a sort without using an index, or a group by without loose index scan).  If this happens, the temporary table will show up using the `show profiles` feature.
- Finally, in MySQL 5.6+ the retrieve from the storage engine can be batched ([BKA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-bka-optimization.html)).  This is probably the case you were hinting at, the buffer that fills is called `join_buffer_size`.